# Hibernate/Lucene search: Wildcard query

Tags: hibernate, search, lucene, wildcard, hibernate-search

I am trying to implement a wildcard query, but I am stuck...  Can anyone help me?

If the user is search for instance for AB, I want to return all results matching something like the regular expression "A[/.-'+&, ]{0,1}B[/.-'+&, ]{0,1}".  I know regular expressions can't be used, but I just want to indicate the expected result.

So, searching for "AB" should return results like: "ABC x", "abc x", "Abcdefg", "A.b.c.", "A-B-C", "A B C d", "Table".

I created a model using this analyser:

```
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name = "abAnalyzer", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class), filters =
{
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class, params =
    {
        @Parameter(name = "ignoreCase", value = "true")
    })
})
public class Foo
{
    ...
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    @Analyzer(definition = "abAnalyzer")
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

I implemented a query like you can see below.  I get all expected results, except the the result like "A.b.c".  What am I doing wrong?  Where did I misunderstood things?

```
public List<Foo> getResults(final String searchName)
{
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    Transaction tx = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();

    BooleanQuery bQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    Analyzer analyzer = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().getAnalyzer("abAnalyzer");

    QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "name", analyzer);
    String cleanedText = qp.parse(searchName).toString("name");
    String[] tokenized = cleanedText.split(""); // split on each character

    QueryBuilder qBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Foo.class).get();

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("name").matching("*" + cleanedText + "*").createQuery();
    bQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

    query = qBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("name").matching("*" + createSearchString(cleanedText) + "*").createQuery();
    bQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

    org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(bQuery, Company.class);    
    return hibQuery.list();
}

....

private String createSearchString(final String name)
{
    StringBuilder searchName = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
    {
        if (searchName.length() > 0)
        {
            searchName.append("?");
        }
        searchName.append(name.charAt(i));
    }

    return searchName.toString();
}
```

I based my code on these resources:

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-querydsl
- http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_Hibernate_Search_Project#Wildcard_queries
- [How to search fields with wildcard and spaces in Hibernate Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285117/how-to-search-fields-with-wildcard-and-spaces-in-hibernate-search)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution...  The Lucene index is generated based on lowercase strings and "special" characters are removed in the index.

So, I changed my model to:

```
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name = "abAnalyzer", charFilters =
{
    @CharFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory.class, params =
    {
        @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = Company.PATTERN),
        @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = Company.REPLACEMENT_PATTERN)
    })
 }, tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class), filters =
{
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class), @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
})
public class Foo
{
    public static final String PATTERN = "(A-Z)*[\\/\\.\\-'+&, ](A-Z)*";
    public static final String REPLACEMENT_PATTERN = "$1$2";

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    @Analyzer(definition = "abAnalyzer")
    private String name;

    ....
}
```

And for querying I implemented this:

```
public List<Foo> getResults(final String searchName)
{
    List<Foo> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // remove "special chars from searchName"
    String searchName = name.replaceAll(Company.PATTERN, Company.REPLACEMENT_PATTERN);

    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    try
    {
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
        Transaction tx = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();
        Analyzer analyzer = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().getAnalyzer("abAnalyzer");

        QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "name", analyzer);
        String cleanedText = qp.parse(searchName).toString("name");

        BooleanQuery bQuery = new BooleanQuery();
        bQuery.add(new WildcardQuery(new Term("name", "*" + cleanedText + "*")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

        org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(bQuery, Company.class);

        result = hibQuery.list();
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```